# find by param node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying use find function to get data from my DB in mLab. I wrote this code, but I am getting an empty string.
My schema had id, name, course and grade.
It works for me when I want the file of the name but not for id. I guess it's because of the extra _id files that the mLab adds.
How do I fix it to get back the JSON that fits the id (let's say id=1)?

```
     app.get('/getStudentById/:id', function(req, res) { //else if url path is getStudGrade with id param
         Stud.find({id:req.params.id}, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(user);
           mongoose.disconnect();
         });
     })
```

---

### new edit

I have changed the filed 'id' to 'idStudent' in my DB and now it working.

```
Stud.find({ idStudent: req.params.id)}...)
```

but why?

Comment: what is the type of id field example (string, number), and how you send the request.

Comment: how you send the request to fetch the `getStudentById`

Comment: using get and sending it in the url localhost:3000/getStudentById/1

Comment: your code is perfect, just check the id is available or not in database that you are passing in request.

Comment: mongoose create _id field automatically. Remove id field from your schema and then apply condition with _id.

Comment: @JahanzaibAslam, there is no need to remove id field.

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming `req.params.id` actually has a value and `/getAll` shows that all your records have an `id` field set, the only thing that jumps out to me is the fact that your comparing a `string` to a `Number` i.e. `req.params.id` will be a string after deserialization but your schema dictates that the `id` field is numeric.

I am not sure if mongoose uses coercive comparison i.e. `==` over `===` (I doubt it), so in order to be more accurate you should parse your string to `Number` then do the comparison e.g.

```
Stud.find({ id: parseInt(req.params.id)}, ...)
```

Comment: When I do that it doesn't work.. but if I change id to String it does... Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Functions in query clause might not work, so to convert to `Number` just do:

`Stud.find({ id: 1*req.params.id}, ...)`